# How can I wait for response in flutter (dio)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, future, dio

I am doing a get request on the server and on the basis of response status I wanna show a toast on the screen before popping the screen. But because of async/await the data is null and toast cannot be displayed and screen gets popped before. I want to wait for the response message to be shown in toast and then pop the activity.[image: After this button I wanna show the toast.][image: The toast message.]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using then, use await. It is lot more intuitive.

```
onPressed: () async {
    final response = await submitData();
    // here you can show toast or pop or whatever you wanna do
  },


Future<String> submitData() async {
  final resp = await register();
  final statusCode = resp.statusCode;
  if (statusCode == 400) {
    return 'something went wrong';
  } else if (statusCode == 200) {
    return 'success';
  } else {
    return 'something else';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that response in onPressed function is still null. :(

Comment: @Alok-P I order to further assist you, can you edit your question and paste your current code?